# How to pass command line switches to Samsung Stock Browser

Tags: android, networking, browser, command-line-arguments, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 and want to configure my stock browser with some command line switches. Looking for some solutions similiar to how we can pass command line switches to the Chrome browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have the information from that there are command line switches for that browser? Maybe that source is contains the information how to start the stock browser with these switches?

Comment: @try-catch-finally since Stock browser is a fork of chromium, I am assuming chromium flags should work. Question is how do I invoke it? 

For chrome it is, "chrome <flags>".

What would it be for stock browser?